# What is the meaning of "w describes a halting TM" mean?

Tags: turing-machines

I was originally looking for languages that weren't context sensitive.

In Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky_hierarchy), I believe the language $\{w | w \text{ describes a terminating TM} \}$ isn't a CSG. I'm not sure how a TM is "described" by a word. As far as I know a  TM is a 7 tuple??

Also, could you give another example of a language which isn't a CSG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any finite, discrete object $O$, it is always possible to find *some* way to encode $O$ as a string. The Turing machine (the 7-tuple you mention) is a finite, discrete object; therefore, you can design a string representation of it. The remark on Wikipedia is that the language encompassing all string representations for machines *that halt* is not a CSG, whatever your encoding scheme is.

More details on that encoding are found in [these course notes](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs103/cs103.1134/lectures/19/Small19.pdf) and [this CS Stack Exchange question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/90259/why-can-we-assume-an-algorithm-can-be-represented-as-a-bit-string/90261).

As far as examples, Wikipedia is a good source. The [true formulas in Presburger arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_language) and (though it's a bit silly, given your example) the set of Java programs that terminate are not expressible in a CSG.